# generate list of successive numbers within some range increasing by 0.1

Tags: python, numpy

i want to generate a successive list of numbers within some range e.g. [1,10],
the output should be as given below:

> [1,1.1,1.2,1.3,.....10]

i tried using `range(-10,10)`

```
m = 0.5*(Y_pred+Y_train)
JS = {}
for alpha in range(-10,10):
  def jsd(p, q, alpha):
    return np.sum(np.sqrt(p+alpha) * np.log(np.sqrt(p+alpha) / np.sqrt(q+alpha)))
  JS[alpha] = 0.5*jsd(Y_pred,m,alpha)+0.5*jsd(Y_train,m,alpha)
```

i want to generate a dictionary JS, in which value should be present for each value of alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your answer is tagged with numpy, use the `arange()` function:

```
np.arange(start, stop, step)
```

And cast it as a list:

```
nums = list(np.arange(-10, 10, .1))
```

---

If you'd prefer not to use numpy you can also generate integers with `range()` and divide them.

With a list comprehension:

```
nums = [x / 10 for x in range(10, 101, 1)]
```

Or a generator comprehension:

```
nums = (x / 10 for x in range(10, 101, 1))
```

Or with `map()`:

```
nums = map(lambda x: x / 10.0, range(10, 101, 1))
```